# Override default behavior of navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice()

Tags: google-chrome, bluetooth, web-bluetooth

When I call navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({acceptAllDevices: true}), a chrome window pops up with the devices around me.  I can only pick 1 device here. Is there a way to pick multiple devices or not have this window pop-up; Can I implement my own web based window that show BLE devices around me?

```
navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({acceptAllDevices: true})
         .then(device => {
              console.log(device);
         });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Web Bluetooth GATT Communication API does not allow you to bypass this prompt. See https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/interact-with-ble-devices-on-the-web#request_bluetooth_devices

The upcoming Web Bluetooth Scanning API however will let you scan for nearby advertisements and connect to devices: https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/scanning.html

It is not fully implemented yet in Chrome.
Follow https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/blob/master/implementation-status.md to keep track of changes.

Comment: Will it be a possibility to connect 2 devices at the same time?

Comment: You can have 2 devices connected. One after the other yes.

Comment: @FrançoisBeaufort when can we expect the requestLeScan API?

Comment: No ETA. I'd suggest you star chromium bug at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=897312.

Answer (score 0):

The new `navigator.bluetooth.getDevices` API (in Chrome 85 and later) actually allows you to avoid this prompt **IF** you've previously used `requestDevice` to pair a device.

The chromestatus page on it is here: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4797798639730688

And it contains a link to a developer guide.

The simplest hackiest use would be:

```
navigator.bluetooth.getDevices().then(function(devices) {
  if (devices.length==0) put_up_button_for_requestDevice();
  else return devices[0].gatt.connect();
}).then(finish_connecting_as_normal)
```